# Determine whether following series converges::

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

[image]
My thoughts:
When n approaches infinity

[image]

so given series diverges by Comparison test because $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. Firstly, I wonder if I am correct on this one. And would there be another, better possible solution for this series?

Comment: Does the series in question have $n^3$ on the denominator of the summand (as it is in the second expression) or not (as it is in the first)? It's kinda important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, best case scenario, $\sin(x) = 1$, in which case the denominator is maximized.  Hence, we have:

$$\frac{n^2 + 3}{n^3(2+\sin(n\pi/2))} \geq \frac{n^2 + 3}{3n^3} = \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{n^3}$$

From here, a quick glance at the integral test will confirm that this series is indeed divergent since $\ln(x)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Since the post changed, modify your good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is basically correct and a good approach to dealing with series at this level (viz, comparison test with the harmonic series). I would say you need more intermediate steps though.

$$s_n = \frac{n^2 + 3}{n^3(2 + \sin(n\pi/2))}$$

We want to establish $s_n \geq 1/n$ so we want a lower bound on $s_n$ so we want an *upper bound* on the denominator of $s_n$. Now we know $\sin \leq 1$ Hence,

$$
\begin{align*}
(2 + \sin(n\pi/2)) \leq 3
\end{align*}
$$
and thus
$$ s_n \geq \frac{n^2 + 3}{3n^3} \geq \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{for $n$ sufficiently large}
$$

Comment: Note of course that "$\text{for $n$ sufficiently large}$ is a bit cheeky as only $n=1$ fails!

Answer (score 1):

You can do quite simple : just look at the denominator. There, $sin(\ldots)$ is between $-1$ and $1$ so :

$0 \leq (2 + sin(\frac{n \pi}{2})) \leq 3$ hence $\frac{n^2 + 3}{(2 + sin(\frac{n \pi}{2}))} \geq \frac{n^2 + 3}{3}$ and the term not only doesn't even go to zero, it goes to infinity and the serie surely diverges